# How to use embedded MongoDB with SpringBoot v2.6.2?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, junit5

I'm using Spring Boot v2.6.2 and Java v17 and trying to test my MongoConnection without having a MongoDBService running because it should be tested with embedded in-memory MongoDB on the build machine, no need to set up an extra MongoDB service there.
For sure on the productive system, it should use a full MongoDB.

I try to get this easy example running:

```
@DataMongoTest
public class MongoTest
{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @AfterEach
    void cleanUpDatabase()
    {
        this.userRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void bootstrapTestDataWithMongoTemplate() {
        final var restaurant = new User( "123", "ABC", "DEF" );
        this.userRepository.insert( restaurant );

        final var found = this.userRepository.findByFirstName( "ABC" );

        System.out.println( found );
    }
}
```

`UserRepository` is an interface that extends `MongoRepository`. `User` itself is just a `DBEntity` with `@Document` annotation. If I let the SpringBoot application run, not in test mode, everything works fine, because MongoDB is running at the specified location. But for the test, I want to let it run as an in-memory DB.

But Springboot wants to connect for the test.

```
    2022-01-20 08:31:57.489  INFO 3976 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2022-01-20 08:31:57.521  INFO 3976 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:152) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? Is `@DataMongoTest` testing in the wrong way? I thought the integrated flapdoodle dependency would inject it automatically in the test case.

The pom itself is also not that complex:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.openjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.erosb</groupId>
            <artifactId>everit-json-schema</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The documentation states:

> 2.2.4. Embedded Mongo
>
> Spring Boot offers auto-configuration for Embedded Mongo. To use it in
> your Spring Boot application, **add a dependency on
> de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo** and set the
> **spring.mongodb.embedded.version property** to match the version of
> MongoDB that your application will use in production.     The default
> download configuration allows access to most of the versions listed in
> Embedded Mongo’s Version class as well as some others. Configuring an
> inaccessible version will result in an error when attempting to
> download the server. Such an error can be corrected by defining an
> appropriately configured DownloadConfigBuilderCustomizer bean.
>
> The port that Mongo listens on can be configured by setting the
> spring.data.mongodb.port property. To use a randomly allocated free
> port, use a value of 0. The MongoClient created by
> MongoAutoConfiguration is automatically configured to use the randomly
> allocated port.   If you do not configure a custom port, the embedded
> support uses a random port (rather than 27017) by default.
>
> If you have SLF4J on the classpath, the output produced by Mongo is
> automatically routed to a logger named
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo.
>
> You can declare your own IMongodConfig and IRuntimeConfig beans to
> take control of the Mongo instance’s configuration and logging
> routing. The download configuration can be customized by declaring a
> DownloadConfigBuilderCustomizer bean.

Therefore add the below dependency in scope:test if you want it to only be applied for Tests.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

As well you need to set the version in your application.properties file:

```
spring.mongodb.embedded.version=4.0.21
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/data.html#data.nosql.mongodb.embedded

---

Working Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.mongodb.embedded</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mongodb-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for usage of embedded mongodb</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>none</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Long> {

    //Spring converts this to Regex findByFirstnameRegex(String firstname)  {"firstname" : {"$regex" : firstname }}
    // automatically
    public List<User> findByFirstName(String firstName);

}
```

User:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}
```

Test:

```
@DataMongoTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class UserControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @BeforeAll
    public void setup(){

        userRepository.save(User.builder().id(1L).firstName("James").lastName("Bond").build());
        userRepository.save(User.builder().id(2L).firstName("James").lastName("Farley").build());
        userRepository.save(User.builder().id(3L).firstName("Marley").lastName("Hemp").build());
        userRepository.save(User.builder().id(4L).firstName("James").lastName("Bond").build());

    }

    @Test
    public void test_getById_successfull() throws Exception {
        Assertions.assertEquals("James", userRepository.findByFirstName("James").get(0).getFirstName());
    }

}
```

src/test/resources/application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.mongodb.embedded.version=4.0.2
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed the application.property file in test resources.

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't accept 4.4.3 and only 4.0.9; I am making reference to spring.mongodb.embedded.version

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else from the future that stumbles upon this while trying to get embedded mongo working - Spring apparently removed the built-in support starting in v2.7.0, so the original flapdodle module no longer works for newer versions of Spring. Thankfully, flapdoodle has 'sister' modules you can import instead that should provide the same functionality, albeit with a little different configuration. They can be found via the [original module's documentation](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo#spring-integration).